# Calculating ET using MODIS product in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis

I extracted monthly ET values using MODIS product (MOD16A2 Version 6 Evapotranspiration) in Google Earth Engine. I multiplied the pixel values with the scale factor of 0.1 as identified in the ET band description. The monthly value ranges are around 10 times lower than the established and authentic literature defined values. I suspect that the asset has already corrected/adjusted the pixel values for the scale factor.

If anyone else has same observations, please share. Does anyone have an explanation to identify where I went wrong?

Code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/5bace683faa21d839af3f2d976918736

```
var pakistan = districts.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_CODE', 188)); //188 pakistan

var target_districts = ee.Filter.inList('ADM2_CODE', [23689, 40407]);// Sanghar = 23689, Umerkot=40407

var district = pakistan.filter(target_districts); 
var indusBasin = basins.filter(ee.Filter.eq('HYBAS_ID', 4030033640));

//Map.addLayer (pakistan);

// Set your ROI,
var roi = district;

// Center the map on region of interest
Map.centerObject(roi,6);

// Add layer to the map
Map.addLayer(roi,{}, 'ROI')

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// EXERCISE 1: Obtain annual ET image and zonal statistics 
// -------------------------------------------------------------------

// set period for Annual ET (select any one year)
var startyear = 2022;
var startmonth = 1;
var startday = 1;

var endyear = 2023;
var endmonth = 1;
var endday = 1;

var startdate = ee.Date.fromYMD(startyear,startmonth,startday);
var enddate = ee.Date.fromYMD(endyear,endmonth,endday);

//Apply Scale factor on ET Band= 0.1
var ET = modET.map(function(img) {
  return img.select('ET').multiply(0.1).copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
});


// Get annual ET
//var ET = modET.select('ET');
var filteredET = ET.filterDate(startdate,enddate);
var ETSum = (filteredET.sum()).rename('modET');

var evapotranspirationVis = {
  min: 20.0,
  max: 700.0,
  palette: [
    'ffffff', 'fcd163', '99b718', '66a000', '3e8601', '207401', '056201',
    '004c00', '011301'
  ],
};

Map.addLayer(ETSum.clip(roi),evapotranspirationVis,'MOD16 Annual ET');


// -----------------------------------------------------------------
//            GENERATION OF ET LEGEND 
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

// Create a legend panel.
var legend = ui.Panel({
  style: {
    position: 'bottom-right'
  }
});

// Create and add the legend title.
var legendTitle = ui.Label({
  value: 'ET Legend',
  style: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: '18px',
    margin: '0 0 4px 0',
    padding: '0'
  }
});
legend.add(legendTitle);

// Create and add the legend entries.
var makeRow = function(color, name) {
  // Create the label that displays the color and name.
  var colorBox = ui.Label({
    style: {
      backgroundColor: '#' + color,
      padding: '8px',
      margin: '0 0 4px 0'
    }
  });
  var description = ui.Label({
    value: name,
    style: {
      margin: '0 0 4px 6px'
    }
  });
  // Return the panel that contains the label.
  return ui.Panel({
    widgets: [colorBox, description],
    layout: ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal')
  });
};

var palette = evapotranspirationVis.palette;
for (var i = 0; i < palette.length; i++) {
  var color = palette[i];
  var name = evapotranspirationVis.min + i * (evapotranspirationVis.max - evapotranspirationVis.min) / (palette.length - 1);
  legend.add(makeRow(color, name));
}

// Add the legend panel to the map.
Map.add(legend);

// -----------------------------------------------------------------

// Check the number of images within the time range
var formatDate = function(date){
  var formattedDate = ee.Date(date).format('YYYY-MM-dd')
  return formattedDate
}
print('Number of images within the time range:', filteredET.size().getInfo())
print('List of dates within the time range:',
filteredET.aggregate_array('system:time_start').map(formatDate));

// Get ET statistics
var ZonalMeanET = ETSum.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(),roi,500);
print("Zonal mean ET", ZonalMeanET);

var ZonalMaxET = ETSum.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.max(),roi,500);
print("Zonal max ET", ZonalMaxET);

var ZonalMinET = ETSum.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.min(),roi,500);
print("Zonal min ET", ZonalMinET);



// -------------------------------------------------------
// EXERCISE 2: Calculate evapotranspiration for each month
// -------------------------------------------------------

// set monthly ET time-series period
var startyear1 = 2001;
var endyear1 = 2022;


// Calculate the ET for each month
var months = ee.List.sequence(1,12);
var years = ee.List.sequence(startyear1,endyear1);

var monthlyET =  ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function (y) {
  return months.map(function(m){
  var w = filteredET.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
          .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
          .sum()//.multiply(0.1)
          ;
  return w.set('year', y)
          .set('month', m)
          .set('date', ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1))
          .set('system:time_start',ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1)) 
                        
});
}).flatten());



print(monthlyET)

// setup the chart
var chartOptions = {
  title: 'Average Monthly Evapotranspiration',
  hAxis: {title: 'Time', format: 'MM-yy', gridlines: {count: 12}},
  vAxis: {title: 'Total ET (kg/m^2/month)'},
};

// Declare and print the chart
var monthlyETchart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: monthlyET, 
  region: roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale:500,
})
  .setChartType('LineChart')
  .setOptions(chartOptions);

// Plot the chart    
print('Average Monthly Evapotranspiration', monthlyETchart)

// EXERCISE 3


// Convert Kelvin to degree C for every image in Collection
 
var modLST = modLST.map(function(img) {
  return img.select('LST_Day_1km').multiply(0.02)
  .subtract(273.15).copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
});


var landSurfaceTemperatureVis = {
  min: -10,
  max: 40,
  palette: [
    'blue', 'lightblue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red'
  ],
};

Map.addLayer(modLST.filterDate('2023-03-20','2023-03-24').mean().clip(roi),landSurfaceTemperatureVis, 'MOD LST')

// -----------------------------------------------------------------
//            GENERATION OF ET LEGEND 
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

// Create a legend panel.
var LSTlegend = ui.Panel({
  style: {
    position: 'bottom-left'
  }
});

// Create and add the legend title.
var LSTlegendTitle = ui.Label({
  value: 'LST Legend',
  style: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: '18px',
    margin: '0 0 4px 0',
    padding: '0'
  }
});
LSTlegend.add(LSTlegendTitle);

// Create and add the legend entries.
var makeRow = function(color, name) {
  // Create the label that displays the color and name.
  var colorBox = ui.Label({
    style: {
      backgroundColor: color,
      padding: '8px',
      margin: '0 0 4px 0'
    }
  });
  var description = ui.Label({
    value: name,
    style: {
      margin: '0 0 4px 6px'
    }
  });
  // Return the panel that contains the label.
  return ui.Panel({
    widgets: [colorBox, description],
    layout: ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal')
  });
};

var palette = landSurfaceTemperatureVis.palette;
for (var i = 0; i < palette.length; i++) {
  var color = palette[i];
  var name = landSurfaceTemperatureVis.min + i * (landSurfaceTemperatureVis.max - landSurfaceTemperatureVis.min) / (palette.length - 1);
  LSTlegend.add(makeRow(color, name));
}

// Add the legend panel to the map.
Map.add(LSTlegend);

// -----------------------------------------------------------------

// Export classified map as GeoTIFF
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ETSum.clip(roi),
  description: 'imageToGeoTiff',
  scale: 500,
  region: roi,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  formatOptions: {
    cloudOptimized: true
  }
});

var yearsTimeseries = ee.List.sequence(2015,2022);

// Functions to get monthly data

var dailyToMonthlySum = function(imageCollection){
  return yearsTimeseries.map(function (y) {
  return months.map(function(m){
  var filteredCollection = imageCollection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
          .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
          .sum();
  return filteredCollection.set('year', y)
                           .set('month', m)
                           .set('date', ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1))
                           .set('system:time_start',ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1)) ;
                        
});
})};


var dailyToMonthlyMean = function(imageCollection){
  return yearsTimeseries.map(function (y) {
  return months.map(function(m){
  var filteredCollection = imageCollection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
          .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
          .mean();
  return filteredCollection.set('year', y)
                           .set('month', m)
                           .set('date', ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1))
                           .set('system:time_start',ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1)) ;
                        
});
})};

var monthlyprcp = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(dailyToMonthlySum(chirps).flatten()); 
var monthlyLST = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(dailyToMonthlyMean(modLST).flatten());
//var monthlyET = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(dailyToMonthlySum(ET).flatten());

// Monthly PRCP
var monthlyPRCPchart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: monthlyprcp, 
  region: roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale:5000,
})
  .setChartType('LineChart')
  .setOptions({
  title: 'Average Monthly Precipitation',
  hAxis: {title: 'Time', format: 'MM-yy', gridlines: {count: 12}},
  vAxis: {title: 'Total prcp (mm/month)'},
});

print('Average Monthly Precipitation', monthlyPRCPchart);

// Monthly LST
var monthlyLSTchart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: monthlyLST, 
  region: roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale:1000,
})
  .setChartType('LineChart')
  .setOptions({
  title: 'Average Monthly LST',
  hAxis: {title: 'Time', format: 'MM-yy', gridlines: {count: 5}},
  vAxis: {title: 'LST (ºC)'},
});

print('Average Monthly LST', monthlyLSTchart);


// Plot MERGE Timeseries
var mergedFeatures = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: monthlyLST.merge(monthlyprcp).merge(monthlyET), 
  region: roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale:5000,
  xProperty: 'date'
  
})

print('Merged graph', mergedFeatures);
```